# Buscar métricas parecidas pela API do Youtube

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, youtube-api, api-youtube

Estava vendo a documentação da [API do Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), mas não consegui ver com clareza a seguinte situação:

Como eu poderia comparar métricas (ou dados) de meus dois canais ou os vídeos dos mesmos, tendo no banco de dados as 2 chaves de API?

Por exemplo, eu estou no canal do meu sistema e tem um botão onde eu clico para fazer a pesquisa, usando os dados do próprio canal, para pesquisar canais semelhantes no sistema. Teria como fazer isso?

Não comecei a desenvolver ainda, ainda é só uma ideia, mas não consegui ver na documentação um meio de fazer isso. Alguma recomendação?

OBS.: Provavelmente usarei PHP (Laravel) para o back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comparar os canais vocês precisará analisar os dados dos canais, e para conseguir os dados você vai necessitar de duas chaves de api. A comparação terá de ser manual, você pode comparar por tags de videos, porém fica dependendo da categorização do gerador de conteudo.